# Solving for X with negative indice

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given a question in class and was asked to solve for x.

This was the question:

(2x-3)^-1/2  =1

I simplified the negative indice into positive:

1/(2x-3)^2  =1 
but I wasn't sure how to finish solving for x

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{(2x-3)^{-1}}2 =1$ or $(2x-3)^{-1/2} =1$? Either way, there is no obvious way to arrive from that at $1/(2x-3)^2 =1$, which is in fact $(2x-3)^{-2} =1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}\require{cancel}
(2x-3)^{-1/2} =1 & \iff \left[\frac{1}{2x-3}\right]^{1/2}=1 \\
&\iff \frac{1}{2x-3}=1\\ &\iff \cancel{\color{blue}{(2x-3)}}\times\frac1{\cancel{2x-3}}=1\times \color{blue}{(2x-3)}\\
&\iff 2x-3=1\\ &\iff 2x=4\\&\iff \boxed{x=2} 
\end{align*}$$

In simple terms, we have a number whose inverse square root is 1, that means that number must be equal to 1 since $\sqrt{1/n}=1$ implies that the term inside is 1, which is only possible if $n=1$. And that's basically what we did, but we were a lot more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You have been given $$(2x-3)^{\frac{-1} {2}}=1$$ For example, you can start squaring both sides to arrive to $(2x-3)^{-1}=1$. Now, multiply both sides by $(2x-3)$.

I am sure that you can take from here.